# What is the purpose of editorial comments in Informants?

Tags: books, annotation

I was browsing an old Informant today and came across an editorial comment, marked with RR. I've seen several of them at the beginning of a game that reference another game, involving a completely different opening, by other players. What is the purpose of these comments?

Comment: RR = Redaction Remark, meaning they consider recommended line to be better, or game/line they pointed out is relevant...

Comment: I think this  sometimes was a way for the editors to include games that didn't quite make the selection, but still had some interresting opening play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RR` = `Redaction Remark`, meaning they consider recommended line to be better, or that the game/line they pointed out is relevant...

`{Credit to AlwaysLearningNewStuff's comment above}`